# Swift Class does not conform to Obj-C Protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, protocols

I'm getting an error that says that RTCPeerConnectionObserver does not conform to protocol RTCPeerConnectionDelegate. Am I missing anything?

Here's RTCPeerConnectionDelegate:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "RTCTypes.h"

@class RTCDataChannel;
@class RTCICECandidate;
@class RTCMediaStream;
@class RTCPeerConnection;

// RTCPeerConnectionDelegate is a protocol for an object that must be
// implemented to get messages from PeerConnection.
@protocol RTCPeerConnectionDelegate<NSObject>

// Triggered when there is an error.
- (void)peerConnectionOnError:(RTCPeerConnection *)peerConnection;

// Triggered when the SignalingState changed.
- (void)peerConnection:(RTCPeerConnection *)peerConnection
 signalingStateChanged:(RTCSignalingState)stateChanged;

// Triggered when media is received on a new stream from remote peer.
- (void)peerConnection:(RTCPeerConnection *)peerConnection
           addedStream:(RTCMediaStream *)stream;

// Triggered when a remote peer close a stream.
- (void)peerConnection:(RTCPeerConnection *)peerConnection
        removedStream:(RTCMediaStream *)stream;

// Triggered when renegotiation is needed, for example the ICE has restarted.
- (void)peerConnectionOnRenegotiationNeeded:(RTCPeerConnection *)peerConnection;

// Called any time the ICEConnectionState changes.
- (void)peerConnection:(RTCPeerConnection *)peerConnection
  iceConnectionChanged:(RTCICEConnectionState)newState;

// Called any time the ICEGatheringState changes.
- (void)peerConnection:(RTCPeerConnection *)peerConnection
   iceGatheringChanged:(RTCICEGatheringState)newState;

// New Ice candidate have been found.
- (void)peerConnection:(RTCPeerConnection *)peerConnection
        gotICECandidate:(RTCICECandidate *)candidate;

// New data channel has been opened.
- (void)peerConnection:(RTCPeerConnection*)peerConnection
    didOpenDataChannel:(RTCDataChannel*)dataChannel;

@end
```

And here's RTCPeerConnectionObserver:

```
import Foundation

class RTCPeerConnectionObserver: NSObject, RTCPeerConnectionDelegate {

    var websocketConnection: WebsocketConnection


    init(websocketConnection: WebsocketConnection) {
        self.websocketConnection = websocketConnection
    }

    func peerConnectionOnError(peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection!) {

    }

    func peerConnection(peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection!, iceConnectionChanged newState: RTCICEConnectionState) {

    }

    func peerConnection(peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection!, iceGatheringChanged newState: RTCICEGatheringState) {

    }

    func peerConnection(peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection!, signalingStateChanged stateChanged: RTCSignalingState) {

    }

    func peerConnectionOnRenegotiationNeeded(peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection!) {

    }

    func peerConnection(peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection!, addedStream stream: RTCMediaStream!) {

    }

    func peerConnection(peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection!, removedStream stream: RTCMediaStream!) {

    }

    func peerConnection(peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection!, gotICECandidate candidate: RTCICECandidate!) {

    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to implement the last method in the protocol. peerConnection:didOpenDataChannel:.

Comment: I don't know how this happened. I even counted methods to make sure I had the same number, and matched each. I think I had it, but I wasn't inheriting from NSObject. Then when I inherited from NSObject, I must have deleted the method. Thanks so much. You saved me a ton of time

Comment: You can also mark some of the delegate methods as @optional (unless they are required), then the warning should go away without having to implement those.